# Python Pillow adding border to rounded image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been looking around for this on SO, but did not find an answer for this anywhere. What I am trying to do, is to add a white border to a rounded image. As you may know, when masking an image using Pillow, there is kind of a strange border, which is why I'd like to change that. I am using the following code to round the original image, but have no clue how to add a border to this yet, since it will just create a rectangular border for the original image

```
 def add_corners(self, im, rad):
        circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2, rad * 2), fill=255)
        alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 255)
        w, h = im.size
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
        im.putalpha(alpha)
        return im
```

Hope anyone knows how to do this, any help is appreciated!